# Maximum Call Stack Size exceeded and ENOENT error while using context

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, react-context

I get this error whenever I try to use React context,provider or useContext, any of them causes this

On App:

```
Maximum call stack exceeded
```

On terminal:

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/lck/Desktop/workdir/MathApp/mathapp/http:/192.168.0.4:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.mathapp&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true'
    at Object.openSync (node:fs:585:3)
    at Object.readFileSync (node:fs:453:35)
    at getCodeFrame (/home/lck/Desktop/workdir/MathApp/mathapp/node_modules/metro/src/Server.js:919:18)
    at Server._symbolicate (/home/lck/Desktop/workdir/MathApp/mathapp/node_modules/metro/src/Server.js:992:22)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async Server._processRequest (/home/lck/Desktop/workdir/MathApp/mathapp/node_modules/metro/src/Server.js:403:7) {
  errno: -2,
  syscall: 'open',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  path: '/home/lck/Desktop/workdir/MathApp/mathapp/http:/192.168.0.4:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.mathapp&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true'
}
```

Comment: Looks like somewhere in your application you forgot a `/` in `http://192.168.0.4:8081` and wrote `http:/192.168.0.4:8081` only. That's a relative path.

Comment: Or that's just applied path normalisation, and the actual problem is that you try opening a http resource as if it was a file.

Comment: @Bergi, this wasn't it exactly, but it did give me a clue somehow

Basically I import stuff in index.js files, and export them again, I was importing the context in the index.js from itself, instead of where my context is...

Comment: @Bergi jsut fixed it, that wasn't it ;')

192.168.0.4:8081 is my ip where metro server starts itself

Comment: @Bergi seems like it was indeed that i was importing it wrongly in the index.js file. Somehow React, Metro, Npm or god knows who or what didn't recognize the changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Path to context is wrong.

Basically I import ContextFile.js to index.js, and from index.js access to many things. index.js was importing Context from itself, and not from ContextFile.

At fist when I corrected the files, it didn't work, I don't know while, I even restarted with `npx react-native start`

Big Thanks to @Bergi, what he said helped me a lot to solve it. Sadly I don't know how to tag or message him.

I hope this helps someone else...

[image showing how i structure my files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NUjxP.jpg)